# Deleting object from state removes key of parent object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this object in state

```
 tasks: [
            {
                'Day 1': [
                    {
                        id: 1234,
                        task: 'Task 1',
                        created: 'somedate'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 1235,
                        task: 'Task 2',
                        created: 'somedate'
                    },
                    {
                      id: 1225,
                      task: 'Task 3',
                      created: 'somedate'
                  }
                ],   
            },
            {
              'Day 2': [
                    {
                        id: 12234,
                        task: 'Task 4',
                        created: 'somedate'
                    },
                    {
                        id: 12235,
                        task: 'Task 5',
                        created: 'somedate'
                    },
                ],    
            },        
    ],
```

and function that deletes object of array by given id

```
_deleteTask = (id) => {
      const tasks = [...this.state.tasks];
      const updatedTasks = tasks.map((item) =>   
      { return Object.values(item).map((boxForTask) => {
          return Object.values(boxForTask).map((eachTaskBox =>  { 
            if (eachTaskBox.id !== id) return eachTaskBox

            }));
      })}
      );
      this.setState({ tasks: updatedTasks });
    }
```

it deletes the task containing the id, but also deletes the outer key that marks day. I can't seem to find the answer why actions nested deeply affect the outer key

Comment: it seems the inner map is more of a filter (as you seem to only return it in case it differs from the given `id`) The reason the outer key disappears is because you are returning `Object.values( item ).map`, so in essence, you loop over all the properties, and only return the values. I personally don't see the need for spreading the array, since you map over all anyhow (and thus `updatedTasks` is anyhow already a complete copy)

Comment: Expected return value of `map`s is an object, but you are returning an array (the mapped `Object.values` array).

Comment: If you have full control over your data structure, you may find solving these types of problems becomes much easier logically if you change from dynamic property names `{'Day 1': [...]}` to static property names `{name: 'Day 1', tasks: [...]}`

Comment: By spreading the array (`[...this.state.tasks]`) you are thinking that you are copying the array. In reality you are shallow copying the array. You need to deep copy the array in order to have exact clone of the array. Otherwise you will copy the reference of the deeper nested objects not the actual value. https://medium.com/@ziyoshams/deep-copying-javascript-arrays-4d5fc45a6e3e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following would work for you? This approach achieves the delete/filtering behaviour based on `Array#reduce()`, `Array#map()` and `Object#entries()`:

```js
var state = { tasks : [
    {
        'Day 1': [
            {
                id: 1234,
                task: 'Task 1',
                created: 'somedate'
            },
            {
                id: 1235,
                task: 'Task 2',
                created: 'somedate'
            },
            {
              id: 1225,
              task: 'Task 3',
              created: 'somedate'
          }
        ],   
    },
    {
      'Day 2': [
            {
                id: 12234,
                task: 'Task 4',
                created: 'somedate'
            },
            {
                id: 12235,
                task: 'Task 5',
                created: 'somedate'
            },
        ],    
    }       
]
};


const _deleteTask = (id) => {

  const tasks = state.tasks.map(task => {
     
    return Object.entries(task).reduce((t, entry) => {
      
      const dayKey = entry[0];
      const dayArray = entry[1].filter(dayItem => dayItem.id !== id);
      
      t[ dayKey ] = dayArray;
      
      return t;
      
    }, {});
  });
  
  state.tasks = tasks;
  // this.setState({ tasks: updatedTasks });
};

console.log('Before', state);
_deleteTask(12235);
console.log('After', state);
```

Comment: I know `;` is optional, but it bugs me every time when I don't see them :)

Comment: Fair enough! `;` added - let me know if I've missed any :-)

Comment: Well you obviously didn't miss any before, it is just my personal view :) Any reason why you suggest `Object.entries` instead of `map`? (since you ask, the const declaration of _deleteTask is missing a `;`) :D

Comment: Thanks - if performance isn't a big issue, I'll tend to use `Object.entries` in this way so that the core delete/filtering work can be done solely in scope of the `Object.entries` callback, rather than this logic relying on context data (ie `task`) that's "passed in" via surrounding closure.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as it is, isn't doing what you are expecting it to do, or it does to much (eg, the unneccessary copy of the `state.tasks` into `updatedTasks`). This copy is not necessary, because map will already produce a new array for you, so in a sense you are copying it twice.

You are removing the outer property when you are returning

```
return Object.values(item).map((boxForTask) => { /*...*/ } );
```

as this will go only into the values of each of these properties, you don't have a clue what your properties might be afterwards.

Another interesting piece of code would be the inner `map`, where you should probably use `filter` (otherwise, you would have some `undefined` in the resulting output). A `filter` would just return the matching items, whereas `map` would return all items

To update your current code, you could simply do it in the following way

```
function copyOfTasksWithoutId(tasks, id) {
  return tasks.map(task => {
    return Object.keys(task).map(key => {
      return {
        [key]: task[key]
          .filter(taskWithId => taskWithId.id !== id)
      };
    });
  });
}
```

The result will be a copy of the tasks array, with a matching outer property and the tasks that should be removed will be deleted. It will not mutate the original input, so that would fit your needs in react as well (for this reason, I also print the original array after the filtered one in the below snippet)

```js
const tasks = [{
    'Day 1': [{
        id: 1234,
        task: 'Task 1',
        created: 'somedate'
      },
      {
        id: 1235,
        task: 'Task 2',
        created: 'somedate'
      },
      {
        id: 1225,
        task: 'Task 3',
        created: 'somedate'
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    'Day 2': [{
        id: 12234,
        task: 'Task 4',
        created: 'somedate'
      },
      {
        id: 12235,
        task: 'Task 5',
        created: 'somedate'
      },
    ],
  },
];

function copyOfTasksWithoutId(tasks, id) {
  return tasks.map(task => Object.keys(task).map(key => ({
        [key]: task[key]
          .filter(taskWithId => taskWithId.id !== id)
      })
    )
  );
}

console.log(copyOfTasksWithoutId(tasks, 12234));
console.log(tasks);
```

Comment: Thank you! This explanation is exactly what I needed, now the mess in my head is getting clearer